# Angular application first page loading time issue and its up to 9 seconds

Tags: angular, performance, optimization, page-load-time

I am trying to fully optimize Angular 7 application
and my bundles sizes are:

```
 main.js.map (main) 2.05 MB
 polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 237 kB
 runtime.js.map (runtime) 14.2 kB
 scripts.js.map (scripts) 1.02 MB
 styles.js.map (styles) 381 kB
```

but when i run this command:

```
ng build --prod --aot && gzipper --verbose ./dist && ng run my-app:server:production
```

it make a server.js file with 27mb size and when i upload this to my dev server ,
Application load time is 9.2 seconds

I don't know why server.js file size is so huge.
Can anyone help me to resolve this issue, than i can go ahead with 1 to 2 seconds with my Angular App load time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not using lazy load module feature provided by Angular. Pleas use this. Lazy loading helps keep initial bundle sizes smaller, which in turn helps decrease load times.

More information can be found at 
[Lazy load feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: We are already following lazy load featured modules but after building there is an additional file creating that is server.js and that's size is 27 mb, actually we are making SSR build.
I don't know why this file size is so huge,
and without this server.js file application is not going Live, its showing 502 error.
Can u please help.

Comment: With SSR, Server.ts file is going to be a big what you can try applying gzip compression.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you implement lazy loading feature for your application. Group your components in other of likeness or similarities. These groups are called modules.

Here is the docs from Angular.
https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

It's quite easy to implement.

Comment: We are already following lazy load featured modules but after building there is an additional file creating that is server.js and that's size is 27 mb, actually we are making SSR build.
I don't know why this file size is so huge,
and without this server.js file application is not going Live, its showing 502 error.
Can u please help.